# Are security concepts for ASP.NET WebForms applicable to ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm about to start reading a book about ASP.NET security using WebForms. My test project uses ASP.NET MVC though, but I can't find a book or extensive topic about security in ASP.NET MVC. My question is, would what I learn in the book for security in ASP.NET WebForms be transferable to ASP.NET MVC? Not just the high-level concepts but also the actual implementation/classes or libraries used/etc.? Or should I find another book/resource?

Comment: In short: yes. Everything that applies to security in web forms also applies to mvc.

Comment: @WiktorZychla - well, maybe...  For instance, using web.config location elements for security is not recommended in MVC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Security is a broad topic, and covers everything from file and network security, CLR security, Authentication, Authorization, etc...  Any book you're reading will probably cover a lot of details that are still applicable to the overall .NET system.

However, as of .NET 4.5.1 Microsoft has moved their Authentication system to ASP.NET Identity, which your book probably will not cover.  Identity is used in both WebForms and MVC.  So this is a topic you're going to have to find out more online.

Comment: Thanks Erik, that is fine with me, as I am targeting MVC 4 only.